# How to validate URL taken from TextField?

Tags: blackberry

is there an API in blackberry that can validate URL ? 
i'm using stupid method

```
 startsWith(http://)
```

and read the Index of the string to make sure it contain ".com/" and other strings to ensure it look like a validate URL.
but i feel like it's a stupid and long way to use.
is there any API that can make it easier ?
**I'm looking for away to make it within blackberry APIs not external packages**

Comment: I think there is no direct method for validate an URL. But you can make an instance of `HttpConnection` with the given `url`. If no `MalformedURLException` is thrown or `getResponseCode()` of the `HttpConnection` instance returns expected response code, you can say that the `url` is okay.

Comment: `I'm looking for away to make it within blackberry APIs not external packages` - I didn't understand that line. I think the url validation algorithm can be implemented in purely BlackBerry API since it will require some string/pattern matching only.

Comment: Thank you Rupak, i will give it a try, and i said "within blackberry API" because there is a way to do it with regex. but i was looking for a way to make it within the blackberry API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API the only classes are:

- [`URLTextFilter`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/text/URLTextFilter.html): Useful only to add it to a text field (Call `EditField.setFilter`). It will discard invalid chars.
- [`URI`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/URI.html): It lets you to validate a URI by calling `URI.create`. Of course, not all URIs are URLs, but URLs should be URIs.